# Prove that every group $G$ whose order is the form $|G|=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}p_3^{\alpha_3}$ is not solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Prove that every group $G$, whose order is the form $|G|=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}p_3^{\alpha_3}$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct prime numbers and $\alpha_i >1$, is not solvable.

Any hint or guidance will be great or any reference to study will be great. thanks a lot.

Comment: The statement is not even close to correct. Where did you see this?

Comment: this is from book A course of finite groups by Harvey E.Rose page 242 part 7,can you give me a counterexample?it is very important for me to know that it is wrong statement.

Comment: I cannot find any statement resembling this in that book on that page.

Comment: Perhaps for odd prime numbers?

Comment: The edit has not changed the validity of the claim. Pick pretty much any example and you will see.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft ,in the page that I told you I want to know why the condition 7 is right,and because of this I asked this question.

Comment: But condition 7 is about the existence of elements $a,b,c$ of pairwise coprime orders such that $ab = c$. I don't quite see how the question is related to that.

Comment: I give you some explanations,condition 7 is equal to solvability,in explanation of this condition saying if $G$  has $a$,$b$,$c$ with the condition,the order of $G$ contain at least three prime number,like $S_5$ .I don't understand why it has at least 3 prime number and why $G$ with this property is not solvable.

Comment: Well, if there are three non-identity elements $a,b,c$ which have pairwise coprime orders, then those orders together must contain at least three primes, and hence so must the order of the group. That the condition of the non-existence of such elements is equivalent to solvability is much more involved.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true: counterexample $S_3 \times C_5$, which is a non- abelian solvable group of order $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

Comment: I mentioned in question that we don't want to consider the case $|G|=pqr$.

Comment: @kpax The restriction on the exponents doesn't make the statement true, because every abelian group is solvable.

Comment: @kpax - I see now that you have altered the question. But it is still not true: take my example $G=S_3 \times C_5$ and consider $G \times G$, which is solvable. Maybe you were inspired by Burnside's $p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$-theorem. If that is the case, I deem you question as valid. But with three prime factors in the order, you will find solvable and non-solvable groups.

Comment: A *non-solvable* example of order $2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2$ is $A_5 \times C_{15}$.